# Code to automatically generate meta tags in wordpress is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I need to automatically generate meta tags from content in wordpress, the problem is that the code that I found on many blogs while searching either uses `$des_post = str_replace( array( "\\n", "\\r", "\\t" ), ' ', $des_post);` or `$des_post = str_replace( array( "\n", "\r", "\t" ), ' ', $des_post);`, which offers a security flaw (XSS), not to mention that it doesn't always strip the html tags correctly, so I've modified the code as follows:

```
function gretathemes_meta_description() {
    global $post;
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $des_post = strip_tags( $post->post_content );
        $des_post = strip_shortcodes( $post->post_content );
        $des_post = esc_attr( $des_post );
        $des_post = mb_substr( $des_post, 0, 300, 'utf8' );
        print '<meta name="description" content="' . $des_post . '" />' . "\n";
    }
    if ( is_home() ) {
        print '<meta name="description" content="' . get_bloginfo( "description" ) . '" />' . "\n";
    }
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $des_cat = strip_tags(category_description());
        print '<meta name="description" content="' . $des_cat . '" />' . "\n";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'gretathemes_meta_description');
function gretathemes_meta_tags() {
    print '<meta name="meta_name" content="meta_value" />';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'gretathemes_meta_tags');
```

The problem is that now it doesn't remove the html tags, so I get a meta description like this while verifying with metatag checkers (seo tools):

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>The description goes here.
```

The problem is that html code like `<!-- wp:paragraph --><p>` shouldn't show up.
The thing here is that the function `esc_attr` is getting the html code and copying, isn't there a way to get the rendered post's text instead? Or any other solution?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use [html purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

in your theme's functions.php or plugin file:

```php
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

function better_strip_tags($dirty_html){
  $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
  $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
  return $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to set HTML Purifier to automatically update?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: It's a php script. I'll install it and forget about it. One day it will have security flaws if I don't update it.

Comment: This is another matter, not relevant to your original question. Since you seem to be new to stackoverflow, I suggest you read this in order to get the best help of the SO community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask